# How to use AdMob AdView in my fragment?

Tags: java, android, admob, fragment

How I can use AdMob AdView and InterstitialAd in my Fragment?

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad_mob, container, false);
// Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
        AdView adView = (AdView) root.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to implement `admob` into your android application. Follow every steps mentioned.

[Link to here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: I'm not using Firebase
I'm using com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.+

Comment: I think Firebase is an upgraded version and you can safely use with your current version.